# Ajax updating calendar in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a database of events and i want it to display "today's events".

I have that part working. At the bottom of the page I have a calendar, and when you click on the date i want it to update the listed events to show the NEW dates.

Current I have

```
<% date = Date.current %>
<% @events.each do |event| %>
<% if event.eventdate === date %>
    <%= event.title %><br>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

And the button for example is

```
<button type="submit" id="dateChange" value="01-01-2013">January 1</button>
```

And the jQuery is

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#setdate').html("<% date = Date.tomorrow %>")
 });
});
```

which updates the html to tomorrow (just as a test).

Two questions -> How do I make it update the actual events listed and how do I pull the value of the button and use it as the Date variable?

Unsure what to do in my controller as well, it's only an index function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your controller respond to JS requests and keep the markup generation inside a partial so you can render just that part easily. Also you need to make sure your link/button has the remote attribute set to true or It won't work.

Here's an example I haven't tested it but It should work.

**index.html.erb**

```
<div id="events">
    <%= render( 'events_list' ) %>
</div>
```

**_events_list.html.erb**

```
<% date ||= Date.current %>
<% @events.each do |event| %>
    <% if event.eventdate === date %>
        <%= event.title %><br>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
<%= link_to "#{date.tomorrow}", events_path({:date => date.tomorrow}), :remote => true %>
```

**events_controller.rb**

```
...
def index
    @events = Event.all
    @next_date = params[:date]
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js # By default this will look for views/events/index.js.erb
  end
end
...
```

**index.js.erb**

```
$('#events').html("<%= escape_javascript render( 'events_list', :date => @next_date ) %>");
```

Give it a try and let me know.

Comment: Do you know how I might be able to create a variable that has events where eventdate === date, instead of using the if statement?

Comment: I guess your app uses a database so I would start looking the rails documentation for models and the query interface:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

You could declare a scope in your model to fetch all events for a certain date for instance.